# Most instant way to stream live video to iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, air, rtmp, live-streaming

I'm making an app that needs to send a video feed from a single source to a server where it can be accessed by desktop browsers and mobile apps.

So far, I've been using Adobe Media Server 5 with a live RTMP stream. This gives me about a 2.5 second delay on desktop browsers, which gives me no native support for iOS, but leaves me with the option to use Air to export the app for iOS, which produces a minimum 5-6 second delay.

The iOS docs strongly recommend the use of HTTP Live Streaming which segments the stream into chunks and serves it using a dynamic playlist in a .m3u8 file. Doing this produces a 15+ second delay in desktop browsers and mobile devices. A Google search seemed to reveal that this is to be expected from HLS.

I need a maximum of 2-4 second delays across all devices, if possible. I've gotten poor results with Wowza, but am open to revisiting it. FFMpeg seems inefficient, but I'm open to that as well, if someone has had good results with it. Anybody have any suggestions?? Thanks in advance.

I haven't even begun to find the most efficient way to stream to Android, so any help in that department would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, my plan is to make an iOS app, whether it's written natively or in Air. Same goes for Android, but I've yet to start on that.

Answer (score 1):

In the ios browser HLS is the only way to serve live video. The absolute lowest latency would be to use 2 second segments with a 2 segment windows in the manifest. This will give you 4 seconds latency on the client, plus another 2 to 4 on the server. There is no way to do better without writing an app.

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more clear... I am making an app, so I'm not confined to using the iOS browser, but as far as I can tell, it wouldn't matter because HLS is still the only format natively supported, whether in an app or in the browser.

Comment: In ios8 you can access the video decoder directly, so any protocol should be technically possible. Whether apple allows a non HLS protocol in the App Store is still unknown. My guess is it would be limited to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

15 Second delay for HLS streams is pretty good, to provide lower latency you need to use a different streaming protocol.
RTP/RTSP will give you the lowest latency and is typically used for VoIP and video conferencing, but you will find it very difficult to use over multiple mobile and WiFi networks (some of them unintentionally block RTP).
If you can write an iOS app that supports RTMP then that is the easiest way to go and should work on Android too (only old Androids support Flash/RTMP natively).  Decoding in software will result in poor battery life.  There are other iOS apps that don't use HLS for streaming, but I think you need to limit it to your service (not a generic video player).

Also please remember that higher latency equals higher video quality, less buffering, better user experience etc. so don't unnecessarily reduce latency.